# react-table not sorting decimal numbers correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I'm trying to sort a column with a decimal using react-table, but the sorting is rendering incorrectly.

This is what the order renders when trying to sort the age column from top to bottom:

```
0.89        
0.14    
0.8
```

When it should render this:

```
0.89
0.8 
0.14
```

Demo of issues using codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/new-bird-puhhr?file=/src/App.js

Click the `age` column to re-produce the issue.

I've managed to get it working by overriding the [orderByFn](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useSortBy). But this hack will only work for sorting one column.

```
orderByFn: function defaultOrderByFn(arr, funcs, dirs) {
  if (dirs[0]) {
    return arr.sort((a, b) => b.original.age - a.original.age);
  } else {
    return arr.sort((a, b) => a.original.age - b.original.age);
  }
```

Any help working this issue out is much appreciated.

Comment: It would make it easier to assist you if your sandbox only had the code needed to reproduce the issue. You've got a lot of commented out attempts at sorting and I'm not sure which one you plan on using.

Comment: Hi Nicholas. The codesandbox is initialised with the code to reproduce the error. You can just click the `age` column to get the incorrect results. Sorry, should have been more clear in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply your own sorting logic per column in `react-table`.

As I see on your example you were close to solve the issue by using the `sortType` field to override the default sorting when initializing your columns.

Apply this arrow function in the sortType field of the age column, and sorting should work fine in both ascending and descending since the library will take care of it.

```
sortType: (rowA, rowB) => {
          if (rowA.original.age > rowB.original.age) return -1;
          if (rowB.original.age > rowA.original.age) return 1;
        }
```

See [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-bhaskara-l9c9u?file=/src/App.js) based on your example.